# Ethernet network connection lost after locking or after Screen Saver activation

Tags: network, macos, ethernet

I have configured the Hot Corners as shortcuts for "Put Display to Sleep" and "Start Screen Saver".

Both work as expected, but when the monitor stops, the Ethernet connection is lost and I'm forced to disconnect and reconnect the Ethernet adaptor from the laptop.

How can I solve this frustrating inconvenience?

Comment: Is wifi enabled and running on this laptop as well as ethernet?

Comment: The problem is indipendent from wifi. I have this problem both with wifi enabled (and connected) and with wifi disabled. The only difference is that wifi never lose the connection.

Comment: What kind of adaptor do you use? Ethernet <> Thunderbolt or Ethernet <> USB? What brand?

Comment: Ethernet USB, it's an original adaptor.

Comment: USB may be the culprit. Apple sells [this adaptor](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD463LL/A/thunderbolt-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter) in their stores. Don't try any non-Apple Ethernet <> Thunderbolt. My school tried several models from 3rd party manufacturers and they all failed miserably from dropped packets to no connections at all. Q: did this start happening after weeks/months/years of use, or has it never worked. Also: what model of laptop?

Comment: mmm... I have to apologize. The adaptor is exactly that one. In fact it has also 3 USB ports. However the OS refers to "USB 10/100/1000 LAN", so the reason why I have told you USB.

Comment: The laptop is a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Comment: Initially I didn't noticed the issue, because my wifi was always active. I noticed the issue when I used a virtual machine with Virtual Box, setted to use the Ethernet for connection. I have noticed that the problem occurs only after locking the laptop.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @mvrejin The only solution I've found since now is: use the WiFi connection...

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you can stop this behavior by preventing your machine from sleeping after screen lock:

- Open `System Preferences / Energy Saver`
- Under `Power Adapter`, check `Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off`

Now my Ethernet connection stays connected!